# Add ivars in @implementation

Tags: objective-c

For good encapsulation, decent `Objective-C` programmers put their `private` ivars in a private `extension` declared in the main implementation file, like this:

```
// MyClass.m

@interface MyClass () {
    float value;
}
@end

@implementation MyClass
@end
```

But recently, I found a simpler way to hide `private` ivars: ivars can be declared in a `{}` block following `@implementation`, like this:

```
// MyClass.m

@implementation MyClass {
    float value;
}
@end
```

It is really handy when no private methods but only `private` ivars need to be hidden.

However, I'm not sure about its syntax validity. Can anyone validate or invalidate it with some canonical references?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's perfectly valid and here is a document by Apple talking about it:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW6

I don't personally use it as I prefer the syntax of a class continuation category.

Comment: @cHao yes apple updated their link structure at some point and broke lots of old links from SO posts. Annoying to say the least.

Comment: Here is the updated link: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html - look for the subheading "You Can Define Instance Variables without Properties" a little way down the page.

Answer (score 3):

I was also curious about this. [Here is the updated link from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW6):

> **You Can Define Instance Variables without Properties**
>
> It’s best practice to use a property on an object any time you need to keep track of a value or another object.
>
> If you do need to define your own instance variables without declaring a property, you can add them inside braces at the top of the class interface or implementation, like this:
>
> ```
> @interface SomeClass : NSObject {
>     NSString *_myNonPropertyInstanceVariable;
> }
> ...
> @end
>
> @implementation SomeClass {
>     NSString *_anotherCustomInstanceVariable;
> }
> ...
> @end
> ```