# @implementation classname {}

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I found few codes like this

```
#SOMECLASS.h
@interface SOMECLASS : SOMESUPERCLASS

@end

#SOMECLASS.m
    @implementation SOMECLASS {
        NSMutableArray *a;
        NSMutableArray *b;
        NSMutableArray *c;

        BOOL d;
    }

    @synthesize something;

    - (id)init
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
           //something
        }
        return self;
    }
```

can someone explain me what this actually means ? the @implementation and then '{' some variable declarations here '}' what does this mean ? what are the scopes of the variables declared in here ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add ivars in @implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853585/add-ivars-in-implementation)

Comment: I've searched and couldn't find answer to this question, Guess its not a duplicate..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are instance variables declared in the class implementation.  See [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-TPXREF126) for the official documentation.

Comment: That is not a class extension; it is an implementation.

Comment: Jesse, true enough, I didn't read closely.  I've updated the link to Apple's docs for the correct section.

Comment: are these methods local instance variables ?

Comment: They are regular instance variables and behave the same as if they were declared in the @interface.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to declare variables this way ??

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you where to declare your variables in class.h

or in class.m like this:

```
    @implementation SOMECLASS {
    NSMutableArray *a;
    NSMutableArray *b;
    NSMutableArray *c;

    BOOL d;
}
```

But variables and methods which are not declared in class.h are hidden for other classes so mostly you declare you declare here inner methods and vars.