# Newbie: about ios / objective -c variable definition in a class

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

I am new in objective-c and iOS development. I have a simple question to ask:

I saw in some iOS class implementation file, people use the code like below:

```
@implementation BIDMyController

- (void)viewDidLoad{...}
```

The code above is quite straight forward. But, sometimes, I saw code of class implementation like below:

```
@implementation BIDMyController{
    NSMutableArray *names;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{...}
```

The only difference is that there are curly brackets added, which includes some variable definition. What does the curly brackets & the variables mean? Are they the Object-C style of defining private variables of this class ?? Could someone explain to me?

Comment: Are you sure the second implementation is @implementation and not @interface?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a way of declaring instance variables (ivars) that are only visible internally.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6891326/1597531

Answer (score 0):

First let's explain what are iVars, and then why they're declared on the implementation file:

Those are called instance variables (iVars) they are not specifically *private variables*.

You can change the way iVars behave with the following directives:

```
@private
```

The iVar will be accesible only by the class which declared it.

```
@protected
```

The iVar will be accesible by the class which declared it and by any subclasses. *If you don't declare a directive this is used by default, and explains why you may think this is a way of declaring private variables.*

```
@public
```

The iVar will be accesible from anwyehre.

```
@package
```

Accesible anywhere the app or static lib.

If you feel confused about some terms, don't worry. Most of the time there's no need to write the directive since `@protected` is the default one and it just work fine.

So, a iVars declaration will look like this:

```
@interface BIDMyController{
   @protected
      NSString *protectedString
   @public
      NSString *publicString 
      NSString *piblicString2 //This iVar is public since it's after de @public directive

}
```

I'm declaring variables on the **interface** file, although as you pointed out, they can be declared on the **implementation** file. The only difference is that declaring the iVars on the implementation file is a way of hiding private iVars. [More about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853585/add-ivars-in-implementation)