# iOS: KVO Memory Leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, key-value-observing

**Note:** I am posting this as a reference for other developers that might run into the same issue.

Why do I have a memory leak with this code:

```
@interface SPWKThing : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *things;
@end

@implementation SPWKThing {
    BOOL _isKVORegistered;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"initing SPWKThing");
        [self registerKVO];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key {
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"things"]) {
        NSLog(@"didChangeValueForKey: things have changed!");
    }
}

#pragma mark - KVO
- (void)registerKVO
{
    if (!_isKVORegistered) {
        NSLog(@"Registering KVO, and things is %@", _things);
        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"things" options:0 context:NULL];
        _isKVORegistered = YES;
    }
}

- (void)unregisterKVO
{
    if (_isKVORegistered) {
        NSLog(@"Unregistering KVO");
        [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"things"];
        _isKVORegistered = NO;
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"SPWKThing dealloc");
    [self unregisterKVO];
}

@end

@implementation SPWKViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self runDemo];
}

- (void)runDemo
{
    SPWKThing *thing = [[SPWKThing alloc] init];
    thing.things = @[@"one", @"two", @"three"];
    thing = nil;
}

@end
```

My output is:

```
initing SPWKThing
Registering KVO, and things is (null)
didChangeValueForKey: things have changed!
```

`dealloc` is never called? Why? I am setting `thing = nil` in the last line of `runDemo`!

See a demo project here: https://github.com/jfahrenkrug/KVOMemoryLeak

Comment: Why in the world are you listening to a change on yourself?  Just put whatever code that reacts to the change in `setThings` somewhere...unless this question is an exercise for discussion...

Comment: So what happens if you put a breakpoint in `unregisterKVO`?  Your use of `BOOL` in your implementation is something I've never done before...usually I use a class extension in the `.m` file to put private iVars there...  (i.e., `@interface SPWKThing() {BOOL _isKVORegistered;} @end`

Comment: @TimReddy This is "an exercise for discussion" :) Basically I'm sharing my discovery that overriding `didChangeValueForKey:` without calling `super` causes a memory leak. About the `BOOL`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8853683/171933

Comment: What happens if you remove all the KVO code? Does your `dealloc` get called?

Comment: @Merlevede Yes. If `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` is never called, then the object get correctly dealloced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

**Never override `didChangeValueForKey:`** (at least not without calling `super`). The [documentation does not warn you about this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/didChangeValueForKey%3a).

Use the correct method `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` instead.

This project clearly demonstrates this: https://github.com/jfahrenkrug/KVOMemoryLeak